# Using files in standalone program

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-imaging-library, exe

I wrote some code which writes text on top of a certain image using the PIL library, I want to make a standalone program out of it (like XXX.exe). My problem is that to write on this image, my code needs to get a path to the image file on my the local computer to be able to select it. This means that I would have to always include the image itself, if I wanted to send the program to someone.

The question is if there is some way I could put the image file into the code itself, so that the program would run without needing any other files. (or something similiar my goal is just a working .exe file without any other files needed for it to work)

I am not very experienced in programming so I have no clue how to do that, pls help...

Comment: hi @mike ... a few things: python is an interpreter based language. there is no executable(.exe) or binary generated. Executions happen line-by-line is what that means. So if we want to execute a python script. the format is `python mikes-script.py` is the way to go. Now for the passing the image location, what I would use is a command line argument that is accepted by the script. HTH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[py2exe](https://pypi.org/project/py2exe/) can help. It takes Python sources and turns them into a Windows executable. py2exe allows you to include [data files](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/data_files) if you wish.